# Unity наследование, как изменить переменную в дочернем классе если она наследуется из наследуемого класса?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
public class ClassA : MonoBehaviour
{
   protected string name;

   private void Start() {
      Debug.Log("Hello, my name is" + name + "!")
   }
}
public class ClassB : ClassA
{
   // у этого класса должны быть свои уникальные данные в 
      унаследованной переменной "name"
}
```

Допустим у меня есть общий класс для животных (ClassA), и ещё три класса (к примеру лиса, собака и лось (ClassB) ) У этих животных должны быть свои имена в переменной "name" (чтобы они говорили как их зовут) которая наследуется для всех трех, как это сделать?

Comment: А при чем здесь Unity? Где наследование от `MonoBehavior` или `ScriptableObject`?

Comment: От monobehaviour наследует да, немного обобщил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте свойства

```
public abstract class Animal : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected abstract string Name { get; }

    protected virtual void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log($"Hello, my name is {Name}!");
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    protected override string Name => "Dog";
}

public class Fox : Animal
{
    protected override string Name => "Fox";
}
```

Comment: Абсолютно не рабочий код. Одна из главный ошибок:  'Dog' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Animal.animalName.get'

Comment: @Alegro абсолютно непонятно, как вы это поняли. Нашел и поправил опечатку.

Comment: "правил" спасибо за обратный отзыв

Comment: @Alegro вы когда код копируете, копируйте его правильно, у меня нет никакого `animalName` в ответе.

Comment: @Alegro `'Dog' does not implement inherited abstract member` означает, что свойство базового класса должно быть обязательно переопределено, но это не было сделано. Защита от ошибок: каждый наследник должен иметь свое свойство `Name`, иначе код не скомпилируется. Можно правой кнопкой по классу тыкнуть и выбрать "Implement", свойство автоматически появится, останется только правильное значение ему прописать. Это нормальная история, ничего необычного вы не встретили.

Comment: А нет, работает, извиняюсь. Не понял из-за чего это было. метод Start не должен быть приватным у вас в коде.

Comment: @Alegro _метод Start не должен быть приватным у вас в коде._ не помню, чтобы это было запрещено в Unity, ну допишите ему `protected` тогда. Публичным он тоже не должен быть.

Comment: Ошибка: Animal.Start() virtual or abstract members cannot be private/ Насколько моих познаний в английском хватает, так и пишет.

Comment: @Alegro понял, мой косяк, исправил.

Comment: @Alegro `virtual` Start сделан чтобы можно было его переопределить в дочерних скриптах `protected override Start() { base.Start(); какой-то еще код; }`

Comment: А для чего у вас оператор virtual?  IDE от Visual Studio предлагает использовать оператор new на методе Start класса "Dog" если нужно вызвать base.Start(); Возможно ваш код более правильный, не знаю. Просто довожу до сведений.

Comment: @Alegro `virtual` позволяет делать `override`. `new` это замещение метода, так делать не следует. Проблема в том, что код `new` метода не выполнится если ссылка будет приведена к базовому классу, полиморфизма не будет. Поэтому вместо `new` надо делать `virtual` и `override`.

Comment: @Alegro если кратко и просто, то `abstract` требует обязательный `override`, а `virtual` - необязательный.

Comment: насчет abstact and virtual я знаю, спасибо за пояснение. Просто насчет оператора new видел на одном англоязычном форуме такой способ + сама IDE предупреждает.  Но если так делать не стоит то спасибо за объяснения!

Comment: Можно ещё один вопрос? Меня пугает что в сети таких вопросов как у меня практически вообще не существует, я делаю что-то не так создавая велосипед заново? наследование для этого не используется или как? Я могу найти путь намного легче если в в главном классе "Animal" объявлю переменную так: [SerializeField] protected string name; и теперь я могу спокойно в редакторе Unity для животного назначать его имя в это переменную. НО если я захочу инкапсулировать эту переменную и убрать [SerializeField] то все данные что я вводил в редакторе пропадут... Я просто не знаю как правильно это делать

Comment: @Alegro правильно это познакомиться со `ScriptableObject` и его применением.